# Specific function conditional to dropout in google spreadsheet

Tags: function, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I've look around but I haven't found any post answering my question.
I understand how to do conditional formatting with google spreadsheet, but what I'd love to do is to insert a specific function depending of a selected dropout option.

For example, if you have in column ***A*** the dropout option : **«Member» and «Non-Member»**

In column ***B*** an inserted value: **50$**

I would like to add in column ***C*** a specific function depending of the choice made in ***A***:

Member --> **=B*15%/2**  / Non-Member --> **=B*15%-10%*B**

Any clue how to do that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you heard about `IF` function? `=if(A1="Member",B1*15%/2,5%*B1)`

Comment: I did not! But now I do! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a nested if to handle a blank value.

```
=if(A2="Member",B2*15%/2,if(A2="Non-Member",B2*15%-10%*B2,""))
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: If that works for you, could you please approve the answer? Thanks.